# Accessing python web server from external machine

Tags: python, ubuntu, webserver

I am experiencing problems with visibility / accessibility of my python web server running on Ubuntu. Server code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler,HTTPServer

PORT_NUMBER = 8899

#This class will handles any incoming request from
#the browser
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

        #Handler for the GET requests
        def do_GET(self):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                # Send the html message
                self.wfile.write("Hello World !")
                return

try:
        #Create a web server and define the handler to manage the
        #incoming request
        server = HTTPServer(('', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)
        print 'Started httpserver on port ' , PORT_NUMBER

        #Wait forever for incoming htto requests
        server.serve_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '^C received, shutting down the web server'
        server.socket.close()
```

Calling it **locally** using curl with below command **works** - I receive answer with 'hello world'.

```
curl {externalIP}:8899
```

Opening address in the browser (chrome, ie) fails!

```
http://{externalIP}:8899/
```

ufw status is inactive

iptables as below

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:8765

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Ubuntu has apache2 server installed and opening html files using web browser, external ip and port 80 is working with no problem from above server...

Any ideas what else could I check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing apache fixed this case. I do not know why, because it should block port 80, but it works now after this:

```
apt-get remove apache2*
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be listening on the loopback interface and not the one that is connected to the internet.

Either specify IP or use:

`server = HTTPServer(('0.0.0.0', PORT_NUMBER), myHandler)`

to specify to listen to all your network interfaces.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately after changing first parameter to external ip (and in second attempt to 0.0.0.0) in specified line of code effect is the same. Locally curl works, externally browser time out.

Comment: Is ping working to the other machine? if you telnet to port 8899 from your client what is the response?

Comment: I configured everything using putty (ssh) and I can ping ubuntu. More over there is apache2 configured which I can access to see html documents in html directory. I simply cannot access my web server.